# Illegal offset type whenever I try to use withCount/Exists in MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

in my following eloquent query

```
$user->load([
    'posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->withCount('comments');
    },
])->get();
```

which I assumed would give me results of

```
{
  name: 'John',
  posts: {
    ...
    comments_count: ?
  }
}
```

but instead I got error of `Illegal offset type`, I thought on giving up on **count** and using `withExists` to just tell if there is comments or not, but it still gave me error of `Illegal offset type`

I thought the problem might be because `$user` is **mysql** and the rest are **mongodb** `HybridTrait` but it wasn't the reason

My only workaround that I know is to run

```
$user->load([
    'posts' => function ($query) {
        $query->with(['comments'])->take(1);
    },
])->get();
```

and by that I can tell if it **exists** or not, but I wonder if there is proper solution for this problem other than this workaround to even get the proper count eager loaded.